# PHP ORACLE select not work

Tags: php, oracle

I'm try select from oracle database 10G. PHP 7.0

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select FIO from USERS WHERE FIO='$_POST[name]';");
```

My form:

```
<body>
<form action="list.php" method="post">
 <p>Ваше имя: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
</body>
```

But have error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /var/www/html/list.php on line 11
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which code is there on line 11 and also before it

Comment: oci_execute($stid); echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach ($row as $item) {
            echo "    <td>".($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
        }
       echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

Comment: while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) 11 line

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem is in here :

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select FIO from USERS WHERE FIO='$_POST[name]';");
```

should be as follows :

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select FIO from USERS WHERE FIO=:FIO");
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':FIO', $_POST['name']);
oci_execute($stid);
```